# Issues with test(order()) function

Tags: r

Trying to create an lsmeans plot, which will eventually require use of the CIplot() function...but for now, trying to organize my dataframe to get the proper order for plotting. Code and error are as follows:

```
kidneytest$group = ifelse(grepl("1", row.names(kidneytest)), 1, 2)
kidneytest$Time = ifelse(grepl("Time1", row.names(kidneytest)), 0,
                  ifelse(grepl("Time2", row.names(kidneytest)), 3, 6))

kidneytest$se = ((kidneytest$Estimate - kidneytest$lower) + (kidneytest$upper-kidneytest$Estimate))/2

kidneytest = data.frame(kidneytest)
str(kidneytest)

kidneytest = test(order(kidneytest$Time, kidneytest$group),)
**ERROR in order(kidneytest$Time, kidneytest$group): argument 1 is not a vector**
```

The only bit of code I'm having issues with is the test(order()) function. Any ideas?

EDIT: as requested, a sample of the data:

```
dput(kidneytest)
structure(list(term = c("group:Time", "group:Time", "group:Time", 
"group:Time", "group:Time", "group:Time", "group:Time", "group:Time"
), levels = c("1:chol0", "2:chol0", "1:chol1", "2:chol1", "1:chol3", 
"2:chol3", "1:chol6", "2:chol6"), Estimate = c(282.159339694811, 
301.946562735556, 218.106209331479, 278.600016537778, 220.125471865553, 
283.957825292963, 232.802162857405, 291.392757317408), Std..Error = c(8.40794523399469, 
8.40794523399469, 8.40794523399469, 8.40794523399469, 8.40794523399469, 
8.40794523399469, 8.40794523399469, 8.40794523399469), df = c(114.347481238299, 
114.347481261838, 114.347481242338, 114.347481262107, 114.34748124077, 
114.3474812668, 114.347481236713, 114.347481261623), t.value = c(33.5586557526558, 
35.9120515574646, 25.9404888187949, 33.1353272154239, 26.1806500565144, 
33.7725588583612, 27.6883538579852, 34.6568334126701), lower = c(265.503807843146, 
285.291030883928, 201.450677479821, 261.94448468615, 203.469940013892, 
267.302293441343, 216.146631005738, 274.737225465779), upper = c(298.814871546475, 
318.602094587184, 234.761741183137, 295.255548389405, 236.781003717214, 
300.613357144583, 249.457694709072, 308.048289169036), Pr...t.. = c(4.96472674182406e-61, 
4.16247437604502e-64, 1.00009525670091e-49, 1.85372673746783e-60, 
4.05301284733068e-50, 2.56467802525755e-61, 1.59569552437474e-52, 
1.73283529598042e-62), se = c(16.6555318516646, 16.655531851628, 
16.6555318516583, 16.6555318516275, 16.6555318516608, 16.6555318516203, 
16.6555318516671, 16.6555318516283)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("group1:Timechol0", 
"group2:Timechol0", "group1:Timechol1", "group2:Timechol1", "group1:Timechol3", 
"group2:Timechol3", "group1:Timechol6", "group2:Timechol6"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset using `dput(kidneytest )`

Comment: `Error in test(1) : could not find function "test"`

Comment: What library are you using that defines `test` ?